# how do i the issue when MDTextFieldRound is unknown in kivyMD?

Tags: kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

i have been struggling with MDTextFieldRound. it gives me this error Unknown class  and i dont know why. can anyone help me fix this?

this my code.

MDTextFieldRound:
text: 'username'

i tried running this code

```
MDTextFieldRound:
    text: 'username'
```

but it wouldn't work.

Comment: Can you post the full error message and minimal code that causes the error?

Comment: Try using `MDTextField:` with `mode: "round"`.

Answer (score 2):

MDTextField:
text: 'username'
mode: 'round'

Answer (score 0):

Use
MDTextField:
text:'Username'
mode: 'round'

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).